when an static variable exists with two instances in c++?
I understand the difference between internal and external linkage. but could you please help to understand when a compiler may generate two independent instances for one static variable in c++.

when you have two files , a.cpp and b.cpp and both define static int someInt;, the someInt exist separately between a.cpp and b.cpp. They are two completely different variables in this case.

@Raildex in this case they are two variables. what if there is only one declaration? is it also possible?

There can't be two instances of the same variable. You can have multiple static variables with the same name. It usually happens to beginners declaring them in a header.

static has 3 different meanings depending on context. Please clarify. Global scope? Class scope? Function scope?

Does static thread_local int i; int* p = &i; std::thread t([]{ assert(p != &i); }); count?


There can't be two instances of the same variable. You can have multiple static variables with the same name. It usually happens to beginners declaring them in a header.

–
molbdnilo
